# Marklogic 7 Issue with fn:format-dateTime

Tags: marklogic

In MarkLogic 7.0-4, the `fn:format-dateTime` function seems to return incorrect values when the fractional seconds start with 0.

The below query returns different results in MarkLogic 5.0-5 and 7.0-4

> let $currentUTCTime := xs:dateTime("2014-10-30T15:23:20.092563Z")
>
> return
>   fn:format-dateTime($currentUTCTime,"[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f001]")

Correct result – 2014-10-30T15:23:20.092

MarkLogic 5.0-5 result – 2014-10-30T15:23:20.092

MarkLogic 7.0-4 result – 2014-10-30T15:23:20.930

This seems to be a bug. Does anyone has any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Harry, you're right, that's a bug and it's currently being fixed.